# Угол панорамы Google Street View

Tags: google-maps-api, google-maps

У меня есть некоторый набор панорам, сделанных при движении по улицам из Google Maps. Чтобы проанализировать их мне нужны **углы с севером**(азимут) для каждой панорамы, так чтобы этот угол соответствовал движению гуглокара при съемке, т е направление **по дороге**. Когда я запрашиваю панораму то могу указать в качестве параметра этот угол, но могу ли я средствами api наоборот получить его значение при съемке(или угол с другой ближайшей панорамой)?